# Inverse of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, inverse-function, monotone-functions

This [paper](https://doi.org/10.1080/25742558.2018.1477543) states a theorem that any decreasing convex function has a decreasing convex inverse.

However, $-x^{3}$ is decreasing and convex in the second quadrant but its inverse is decreasing and concave. Could someone clarify?

Also, is there a clear relation between the curvature of a function and the curvature of its inverse (if it exists)?

Comment: The statement in the paper concerns functions $(0, +\infty) \rightarrow (0, +\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Could you also elaborate upon the convexity/concavity relation between a function and its inverse? There doesn't seem to be any clear pattern. Inverse of $e^-x$ is convex but inverse of $-x^3$ (defined on negative x) is concave, even though both functions are decreasing convex. Any thoughts?

Comment: Correction: $e^{-x}$